# Using mosh with Back to my Mac

Tags: icloud, ssh

How can I use [mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu) via iClouds *Back to my Mac*, like I can do it with ssh?

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://onethingwell.org/post/27835796928/remote-ssh-bact-to-my-mac) way? I have never used it but it seems this can just be done the same way with mosh.

Comment: That didn't work. Mosh has recently added some ipv6 support, but I wasn't able to get it to work with BTMM.  https://github.com/keithw/mosh/issues/81

Comment: You can install the version of mosh with ipv6 support with `brew install --HEAD mosh`

Answer (score 2):

I got it working.

It requires a bit of messing with mosh, so try it first with the current version before hacking with your installation of mosh. Leave a new answer or a comment if this starts working with the latest versions of mosh please.

First, on both the client and the server, install the latest version of mosh: `brew install --HEAD mosh`.

Then edit the `mosh` file (`$EDITOR 'which mosh'` (use backticks instead of single ticks)) as specified here: https://github.com/keithw/mosh/issues/81#issuecomment-57074800 
I made the change on both the client and the server.

Then execute `mosh -6 your_server` if you followed Rnhmjoj's suggestion, or `mosh -6 your_server.you_magic_number.members.btmm.icloud.com`

Comment: So cool! I just switched to my cell phone tethered internet and it all just reattached and kept working. Mosh FTW! (And of course my ssh session that I also had running said `Write failed: Broken pipe`)